# Android: ListView doesn't show anything on Tablet mode

Tags: android, listview, tablet

I have an app that supposed to run on tablet and phone. For the tablet layout I create this layout, so it starts two fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/search_panel_fragment"
        android:name="adam.czibere.fragments.tablet.SearchPanelFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="search_panel" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/search_list_fragment"
        android:name="adam.czibere.fragments.tablet.SearchListFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="search_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So far so good, the fragments shows their views. The two fragment's host activity is SearchActivity.

```
    public class SearchListFragment extends Fragment {

private SearchEventListener seListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        seListener = (SearchEventListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement SearchListFragmentListener");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kurva_lista, container, false);


    SearchActivity sa = (SearchActivity) getActivity();
    ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setAdapter(sa.mobileAdapter);

    list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            seListener.onListScrolled(view, firstVisibleItem,
                    visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);

        }
    });


return v;
}

    }
```

When I click the searchbutton on the SearchPanelFragment, it makes a list for the adapter and calls a notifyDataSetChanged(), but nothing can be seen on the screen. I checked, the adapter, it has some values (getgropuCount not gives back 0 ). My adapter's getView method is not getting called at all. The strange thing, that if I try it on mobile phone, it works, it populates the list. (I am using another fragment on phone, but it does the same thing. In phone mode, only one fragment can be seen on screen)

This is the adapter:

```
    public class MobileSearchListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private List<VCDR> items;
VCDR lastElementOnScreen;

private Context context;

public MobileSearchListAdapter( Context c,List<VCDR> objects) {
    items=objects;
    context=c;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item_viewpager, null);
    }
    VCDR currentItem=(VCDR) getItem(position);
    lastElementOnScreen=currentItem;
    TextView date= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView dur = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    TextView caller_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.caller_name);
    TextView caller_num = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.caller_number);
    TextView called_num = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.called_number);
    TextView called_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.caller_name);



    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    date.setText(dateFormat.format(currentItem.getStartTime()) + " " +
                        timeFormat.format(currentItem.getStartTime()));
    dur.setText(timeFormat.format(currentItem.getDuration()));
    called_name.setText(currentItem.getDestinationNameD());
    caller_name.setText(currentItem.getSourceName());
    called_num.setText(currentItem.getDestinationCallerID());
    called_num.setText(currentItem.getSourceCallerID());



    return convertView;
}

public VCDR getLastVisibleElemnt(){
    return lastElementOnScreen;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: How are you telling the adapter about the changed data? Are you creating a new Adapter or modifying the List. Please post the code of the second fragment.

Comment: The second fragment calls a method on the host activity(SearchActivity). The activity makes a server call, and when it returns and fills the list. It calls mobileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the SearchActivity.